# Testing as android.uid.system user

Tags: android, eclipse, certificate, code-signing

I am developing an android app that will run under the android.uid.system user (the tablet manufacturer is signing the app for me so it will be able to run under this user id).

The problem I have is that it takes about 2 to 3 weeks each time I want the app signing. As I make code changes I want to be able to test them under the system user but it is not feasible for me to wait this long to be able to test/debug my changes - especially if they turn out to be wrong.

Is there any way I can test the app on the tablet as the system user (or mimicking system user privileges) without having to get it signed every time?

Further info: 
I am developing on windows 7, using Eclipse IDE.
The tablets are running Android 4.4.2 and 4.4.4 (2 different models).
The tablets are not and will not be rooted.
Assume a fairly basic level of understanding of app signing on my part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no way unless the device is rooted, is there no possibility of a development device you can root and use that does not go out the development environment?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response dave. I can use a rooted device for development purposes. Is your thinking that I would then install the app to the system/app folder? If so does this give the same privileges as running under the system user, or is one more "powerful" than the other? Or is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

### Root the device and install app to system/app folder

I have sorted this myself by rooting the device for development purposes and then copying the app from the data/app folder to system/app and then removing the it from data/app folder.

The device then treats it as a system app and so far all of the system level functions I have tried have been working (such as reboot device and set timezone).

[This article](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/76976/how-to-install-app-as-system-app) helped (although I had to copy (cp) and remove (rm) rather than move (mv) the app).